# Another word for "virgin plastics"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for an alternative for the well established term of "virgin plastic pellets", meaning pellets that have been freshly produced and not used to make a plastic product yet. I'm using it in an academic context where it is well understood, but would like to avoid the term "virgin" (not because I think it is too offensive but to use a more wholesome neutral language).

Comment: The fact that you say you seek a "more wholesome" alternative implies you ***do*** think "virgin" is "offensive". But you're mistaken - virgin forests, virgin copper, *extra* virgin olive oil, etc. are perfectly "neutral" collocations.

Comment: There's irony here on so many levels. Just ... don't. Your job here is to communicate. That's all, just communicate. If you want to toy with the language, try fictional writing.

Comment: I hope you never have to give a briefing on the erection procedures for a Siemens Expando.

Comment: [This pretty formal-looking report](https://www.unrbep.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BusPlans4RecyclingPlastic_Glass_Rubber.pdf) on recycling plastics, glass, and rubber uses the word ***virgin*** no less than 52 times. And it taught me my "new word for the day" - I never knew that [***cullet***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cullet) is *broken or refuse glass usually added to new material to facilitate melting in making glass.*

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a new term?  Bars of iron that have just been extracted from ore and never used are pig iron. Maybe you could call it pig plastic?

Answer (score 4):

Your question says the word *virgin* is "well established" and you're "using it in an academic context where it is well understood".

You don't want to use the word *virgin* because you want "more wholesome neutral language".

*Virgin* **is** wholesome (what could be more wholesome?), and it's entirely neutral. As FumbleFingers commented, "virgin forests, virgin copper, extra virgin olive oil" are neutral collocations, not to mention "virgin snow".

#### There is no better word.

Your audience will expect it and understand it. You're overthinking. Don't make them overthink it as well.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY. I am sick to death of misplaced political correctness. Philosophical question: Is something neutral necessarily "wholesome"? {sigh}

Comment: @Lambie, Please see my edit below.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that specifies the plastic is being used for the first time is **first-use**, a [compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier). In particular, it is often used in contrast to **recycled plastics**, or plastics that are sourced from recycled materials.

Examples:

> For the first time ever, recycled plastics cost more than **first-use plastic** material, according to The Guardian. ([m/Oppenheim](https://www.moppenheim.org/recycled-plastic-costs-more-than-first-use-plastic-creating-barriers-for-a-future-of-less-waste/))

> This card is made of 85% of pre-consumer, post-industrial recycled material. As a result, it contributes reducing the use of virgin PVC, **first-use PVC** by 85%. ([Thales](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/markets/digital-identity-and-security/banking-payment/cards/eco-friendly-credit-card))

> Nonetheless, individuals can abide by the very simple mindful resolution
> of minimizing their use of **first-use plastic** or avoiding it altogether; or, at the very least limiting use of plastics to reusable and recycled forms. (Chiappelli, Francesco, Emma Reyes, and Ruth Toruño. "[Climate Crisis Impact on AIDS, IRIS and Neuro-AIDS](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-29022-1_21)." Global Virology III: Virology in the 21st Century. Springer, Cham, 2019. 575-603.)

> Here they are turned into 100% recycled polyester and nylon pellets, called NetPlus, which are sold to companies as a sustainable alternative to **first-use plastics** ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/apr/24/ocean-plastic-recycling-patagonia-chile))